# Why is use effect rendering the page twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I have data I'm trying to fetch and use with the code below, however when I am logging the value of records I get an empty array first and my fetched object second. Because of this, I'm unable to access the object's information in my app.

```
  const [records, setRecords] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
    async function getRecords() {
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/record`);

      if (!response.ok) {
        const message = `An error occurred: ${response.statusText}`;
        window.alert(message);
        return;
      }

      const records = await response.json();
      setRecords(records);
    }

    getRecords();

    return;
  }, []);

  console.log(records);
```

Comment: `const [records, setRecords] = useState([]);` Your initial value is an empty array, so that sounds correct. It renders once with the empty array, then you fetch, then some time later you set state and it renders again. If you have some code that doesn't work correctly with an empty array, please share that and what you want it to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first render triggers the effect.

The effect calls `setRecords` which triggers the second render.

You need to write your display logic so it can account for `records` defaulting to an empty array.